# Footer menu in html and css

Tags: html, css, menu

How to make this menu footer in HTML and cascading style sheets

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIMmz.png)

how make in cascading style sheets*??

```
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">About Us</a>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Portfolio</a>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Clients</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Events</a>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Media</a>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="">ILorem Ipsum</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: Make a footer and put the html links in there. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean someting like this? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdz68kxk/)

**Html:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Portfolio
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Clients</li>
    <li>Events
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Media
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>ILorem Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

**Css:**

```
body{width:100%;}
ul {width:100%; list-style:none;}
ul li {float:left; width:150px; font-weight:bold;}
ul li ul {padding:0;}
ul li ul li {float:none; padding:5px 0; font-weight:normal;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdz68kxk/

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you expain how this code answers the question?